# how to genrate fake values of latitude longitude variable within some range in python faker library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, faker

I am generating the fake latitude and longitude values using python fake library. But when I run the code to change the real value to fake values it will give me random latitude and longitude values which are very apart from each other and did not connect to real data. for this, I want to make the solution for this purpose I am trying to specify some range to lat-long but I am not able to do. Can we do like it done in `fake.random.number(2,10)` this case.

Can anyone please give me some suggestion so I can able to provide a range for the latitude-longitude point using python faker library?

Comment: There is a `faker` library out there?

Comment: @DirtyBit: https://github.com/joke2k/faker

Comment: @Jan *clicks and starts reading*

Comment: *joins @DirtyBit*